# React Native: Can bundle ID and package name be different?

Tags: react-native, app-store-connect, google-play-console, bundle-identifier, package-name

In my React Native app, the bundle ID (iOS) and package name (Android) are currently the same, but I need to change the package name because I need to create a new app shell on the Google Play console and push my app there. Is it possible to have a package name that's different from the bundle ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes It can be different, cause technically one is an android project, the other is iOS, even though they are the same app. For example if you want to add firebase services to your app, you need to create one project for android and one for iOS in firebase console and they **must** have different bundle ID and package name.